# Excel: Automatically Bring Column Data From One Table into Other Tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery, excel-tables

I have multiple sheets in a excel document.  The first sheet I have is called "Companies" which has a table called "Watchlist".  That table contains a list of companies with some basic data concerning those companies.  So, for example:

```
* Ticker Symbol
  -- MA
  -- MSFT
  -- TGT
  -- etc.

* Company Name
  -- Master Card
  -- Microsoft
  -- Target
  -- Etc.

* Sector
  -- Financial Services
  -- Technology
  -- Consumer Defensive
  -- etc.
* Etc.
```

Now, I have another sheet called "Price" with a table that is also called "Price", which has the following columns:

```
* Current Price
* 52-Week Low
* 52-Week High
* P/E Ratio
* Etc.
```

What I need to do is to automatically import the Ticker Symbol column (with the full list of tickers) from the "Watchlist" table on the "Companies" sheet and add that as a column in the "Price" table on the "Price" sheet.

What I do NOT want to do is to copy and paste the list into the Price table.  I have numerous other sheets and tables besides the Price sheet/table.  Copying and pasting the list into each table is not only tedious, but would mean that I have to maintain the same list in multiple locations (something I don't want to do).

As such, I am wondering what is the easiest and/or most efficient way for me to incorporate the list of ticker symbols from the Watchlist table into the other tables in my spreadsheet?

Comment: How do you plan to match the items from the first table into the second? Or is it a row for row copy

Comment: It's a row for row copy.  In particular, what I want is that when I update the data in the first table that it automatically updates in the second table.

Comment: I notice that none of your prior 9 questions ever ended with an accepted solution, but I'll give it a try

Comment: Thanks.  I would like to note that of the last 9 questions, only 2 had answers and one of them I marked as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

For each of the two data sets, use data.. from table/range... no headers .. file close and load to connections ..

Create 3rd query in powerquery that adds specific column (here **b**) from Table1 into Table2. Sample code to paste into powerquery's home ... advanced editor...

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
custom2 = Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(Source) & {Table1[b]},Table.ColumnNames(Source)&{"New"})
in custom2
```

file close and load as a table. You would then have to refresh every time to make sure that the new table stays updated

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  The only issue is that if I add a new row to Table1 it does NOT show up in column 2 unless I add a new row to table2.  What I need is for that new row to be added automatially.  Any ideas?

Comment: Edited answer above with full powerquery solution

Comment: Thanks -- I did a variation of your answer.  If you want, take a look at it, update yours and I will set your answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

I did a variation of horseyride's answer.

What I did is the following:

- Step #1:  Click on the Watchlist table
- Step #2:  Click on the Data Tab --> From Table/Range

[at this point the table will open up in Power Query]

- Step #3:  Remove the columns I do not want
- Step #4:  Rename the query to the name that I want (e.g., Prices)
- Step #5:  Click on Close & Load
- Step #6:  Click on the New Table
- Step #7:  Click on the Query Tab in the Ribbon Bar
- Step #8:  Click on Properties
- Step #9:  Click on Refresh Every [and set my refresh time]
- Step #10:  Click Okay
- Step #11:  Add other columns and data to the new table